# Failed to lazily initialize a collection no session or session was closed

Tags: orm, coldfusion

When I fill in the value of a property date_declined I get the following error on an unrelated property.

```
Application Execution Exception
Error Type: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException : [N/A]
Error Messages: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: blm_doc.blm_doc_cases, no session or session was closed
```

Answer (score 0):

The ormtype=date was missing from the property definition.

```
property name="declined_date" 
    column="DECLINED_DATE" 
    sqltype="DATE"
    ormtype="date";
```